# xcb_poll_for_event does not detect XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE event for closing window

Tags: c++, linux, xcb

I am porting my application to Linux, and I am using the XCB library for window handling.  I need to detect when the window closes, so that the application can exit.  However, the system cannot block on the main window loop due to the way the system is designed.  This is easy in Windows, since you just use `PeekMessage`.  However, xcb does not seem to work when I try to detect `XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE` using `xcb_poll_for_event`.  The close button on the window in fact has no functionality when I try to inject the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol.

Window setup:

```
// initialize XCB
this->connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
this->screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(this->connection)).data;;

// create window
u32 mask = 0;
u32 values[1];
this->window = xcb_generate_id(this->connection);
mask = XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
values[0] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE;
xcb_create_window(this->connection, 0, this->window, this->screen->root, 0, 0, width, height, 0, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, this->screen->root_visual, mask, values);

// setup close handler event
xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t protocolCookie = xcb_intern_atom_unchecked(this->connection, 1, 12, "WM_PROTOCOLS");
xcb_intern_atom_reply_t* protocolReply = xcb_intern_atom_reply(this->connection, protocolCookie, 0);
xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t closeCookie = xcb_intern_atom_unchecked(this->connection, 0, 16, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW");
this->m_closeReply = xcb_intern_atom_reply(this->connection, closeCookie, 0);
xcb_change_property(this->connection, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, this->window, protocolReply->atom, 4, 32, 1, &(this->m_closeReply->atom));
free(protocolReply);

// map and flush
xcb_map_window(this->connection, this->window);
xcb_flush(this->connection);
```

Message loop:

```
// handle all incoming messages
xcb_generic_event_t* e;
while(e = xcb_poll_for_event(connection))
{
    // take action from message
    switch(e->response_type & ~0x80)
    {
        case XCB_EXPOSE:
            // invalidated
            xcb_flush(connection);
            break;
        case XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE:
            // close window
            if(((xcb_client_message_event_t*)e)->data.data32[0] == (*this->m_closeReply).atom)
                return false;
            break;
    }

    // cleanup
    free(e);
}
```

Window closing works flawlessly when I replace `xcb_poll_for_event` with `xcb_wait_for_event`, but then the window loop is blocked on waiting for messages.  I just need to know what I am doing wrong for the event to never get detected when using `xcb_poll_for_event`.

Comment: Did You check [Api without Secrets: Introduction to Vulkan](https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntroductionToVulkan) tutorial? There is a very simple [xcb window management code](https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntroductionToVulkan/blob/master/Project/Common/OperatingSystem.cpp) that uses xcb_poll_for_event() function. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I got it down to the same function calls as the example and the event is still not being detected.  I am going to try to follow the same example to attempt an XLib implementation instead.

Comment: Did You try to compile and execute samples from the provided link? If they don't execute properly, maybe there is some bug in the Linux distribution You use? Or maybe a different version of xcb (maybe there was some change in the meantime) that requires Intel's samples to also be updated? But if the samples run correctly, then there has to be some difference between Your code and provided samples' code.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  All threads are blocked on a locked mutex, so `xcb_poll_for_event` is not even being called.  I will post this as the answer if I can determine the race condition and get the close button working.

Comment: So I take it you never got this work?

Answer (score 0):

From the [XCB tutorial](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libxcb/tutorial/index.html#register)

> Note: A common bug programmers do is adding code to handle new event types in their program, while forgetting to add the masks for these events in the creation of the window. Such a programmer then should sit down for hours debugging his program, wondering "Why doesn't my program notice that I released the button?", only to find that they registered for button press events but not for button release events.

And in your code

```
mask = XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
values[0] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE;
xcb_create_window(
  this->connection,
  0,
  this->window,
  this->screen->root,
  0, 0,
  width, height,
  0,
  XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
  this->screen->root_visual,
  mask, values  // <--
);
```

You've told the X server to only send you certain events, and you've neglected to include `XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY`.

```
- values[0] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE;
+ values[0] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY;
```